# Stratigraphic plot of geochemical data using ggplot2 and tidypaleo

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a stratigraphic plot of geochemical element data which should be possible using package tidypaleo.

I want multiple plots of the different element data with Depth (cm) downcore set as the y axis. The data look as follows.

[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuQbB.png)

I am using this code:

```
ggplot(wapITRAX, aes(x =BrTi , y = wapITRAX$Depth))+
labs(y = "Depth (cm)")+
geom_lineh()+
theme_classic()+
scale_y_reverse()
```

However, this only plots one element and I am trying to achieve a plot like this [Image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OXtN.png)

```
> dput(head(wapITRAX))
structure(list(Depth = 0:5, IncCoh = c(6.049230907, 5.975282432, 
5.736199822, 5.658584418, 5.659008377, 5.597103404), BrTi = 
c(50.50197628, 
22.09236453, 23.48370927, 18.62638581, 14.36924414, 17.48777896
), AlIncCOh = c(16.69633736, 8.200449193, 23.70907643, 20.32310407, 
28.62692352, 26.44224866), BrCl = c(8.04090623, 4.306048968, 
3.417836951, 3.156895904, 2.787628518, 2.059316731), FeTi = 
c(332.715415, 
235.9371921, 372.726817, 390.7871397, 396.986099, 495.2624867
), CaTi = c(4.071146245, 3.27955665, 4.395989975, 3.677383592, 
3.028670721, 4.523910733), ZrRb = structure(c(363L, 447L, 407L, 
395L, 450L, 410L), .Label = c("#DIV/0!", "0.447638604", 
"0.478169284", 
"0.54554134", "0.548501778", "0.561420163", "0.579454254", 
"0.579498861", 
"0.580801291", "0.589758019", "0.590194076", "0.590277778", 
"0.591357754", 
"0.592870544", "0.593851133", "0.598519653", "0.599931082", 
"0.600979737", 
"0.601426307", "0.611710677", "0.617065868", "0.618499405", 
"0.621310093", 
"0.627720871", "0.63775246", "0.64005168", "0.643958869", 
"0.644371941", 
"0.645605974", "0.645661658", "0.646672915", "0.647348952", 
"0.651578947", 
"0.652401176", "0.656186383", "0.657906264", "0.658835905", 
"0.662074554", 
"0.662361624", "0.669589393", "0.67103429", "0.671371769", 
"0.674335863", 
"0.674781688", "0.676097561", "0.676639083", "0.677849462", 
"0.680497925", 
"0.680610514", "0.680725971", "0.683906537", "0.68855859", 
"0.689067202", 
"0.692353115", "0.692732291", "0.695411392", "0.696067091", 
"0.696794872", 
"0.699376436", "0.701762744", "0.702015197", "0.702432938", 
"0.70361991", 
"0.705235754", "0.705426357", "0.708084164", "0.708258528", 
"0.708925221", 
"0.715226656", "0.715263314", "0.717828827", "0.718975706", 
"0.719799305", 
"0.720363636", "0.72476489", "0.725426857", "0.725461098", 
"0.726030739", 
"0.7267645", "0.726998188", "0.727170554", "0.727533265", 
"0.730362368", 
"0.731182796", "0.735042735", "0.735849057", "0.736184046", 
"0.737214792", 
"0.738692342", "0.742223591", "0.742639327", "0.742714724", 
"0.744126167", 
"0.745790081", "0.746207701", "0.746606335", "0.747041077", 
"0.749019608", 
"0.751204307", "0.751326495", "0.752443737", "0.752994012", 
"0.753398969", 
"0.754587869", "0.755151515", "0.755466053", "0.756316411", 
"0.757107679", 
"0.759175941", "0.76070965", "0.761635833", "0.763760166", 
"0.763861189", 
"0.764076577", "0.765001936", "0.765509391", "0.765795207", 
"0.76598579", 
"0.767080745", "0.767225748", "0.767262192", "0.770291777", 
"0.771194699", 
"0.772540984", "0.774533358", "0.77486376", "0.777252364", 
"0.778319123", 
"0.778445883", "0.779076739", "0.779310345", "0.782186577", 
"0.78238342", 
"0.782541093", "0.785497178", "0.787594824", "0.788230584", 
"0.788916736", 
"0.789033068", "0.789052737", "0.789177605", "0.789596048", 
"0.790439133", 
"0.791078234", "0.792993631", "0.794899978", "0.795265235", 
"0.795432921", 
"0.798130469", "0.79861957", "0.798894446", "0.799410029", 
"0.799679487", 
"0.800096223", "0.800119868", "0.800280899", "0.800947004", 
"0.80293448", 
"0.804118993", "0.804120112", "0.805092452", "0.806161301", 
"0.81631016", 
"0.816337149", "0.81638756", "0.81827622", "0.818899466", 
"0.81993865", 
"0.821925431", "0.825329202", "0.825608077", "0.826135414", 
"0.826325411", 
"0.827108292", "0.829798658", "0.832460733", "0.832814584", 
"0.833845295", 
"0.833908046", "0.833980583", "0.83741705", "0.837604457", 
"0.838292367", 
"0.838860231", "0.839741935", "0.846485664", "0.846740374", 
"0.84679304 
 1", 
"0.84734599", "0.850027518", "0.850077882", "0.854863613", 
"0.85565883", 
"0.85591192", "0.857095047", "0.858967536", "0.85897779", 
"0.859192457", 
"0.859239235", "0.860408412", "0.860505166", "0.8609918", 
"0.862821134", 
"0.867779204", "0.872207328", "0.872918493", "0.873888706", 
"0.874140666", 
"0.877452229", "0.879856851", "0.88003663", "0.880155093", 
"0.881013197", 
"0.882190156", "0.882319978", "0.883029342", "0.883316008", 
"0.884908053", 
"0.885431692", "0.885849846", "0.889082969", "0.89763062", 
"0.898384089", 
"0.898527865", "0.9", "0.900719424", "0.904636261", "0.904913848", 
"0.905223479", "0.908485273", "0.911212059", "0.916470588", 
"0.917162698", 
"0.917470525", "0.917952884", "0.918054256", "0.918781726", 
"0.922268448", 
"0.925987182", "0.926287744", "0.933958724", "0.939701616", 
"0.940987438", 
"0.941196465", "0.943041526", "0.946832078", "0.947419907", 
"0.948080043", 
"0.949085366", "0.950099404", "0.950502912", "0.950704225", 
"0.953596288", 
"0.954868709", "0.95505992", "0.955361596", "0.956422018", 
"0.95671509", 
"0.959064327", "0.96165309", "0.964232489", "0.965528048", 
"0.965874467", 
"0.968717195", "0.970270821", "0.971573209", "0.973415133", 
"0.974608081", 
"0.974986972", "0.978223496", "0.97935022", "0.980142566", 
"0.981730052", 
"0.982819606", "0.987483236", "0.989587207", "0.991002571", 
"0.991932655", 
"0.995306859", "0.997555012", "1.001706485", "1.002357873", 
"1.005146199", 
"1.010493827", "1.011544012", "1.013038906", "1.013469577", 
"1.015357613", 
"1.01541976", "1.015544041", "1.015937059", "1.016162826", 
"1.019393939", 
"1.019529957", "1.019994873", "1.028932491", "1.029518072", 
"1.030101225", 
"1.032310705", "1.03344968", "1.036769138", "1.037322515", 
"1.041150092", 
"1.041459782", "1.041961577", "1.042347697", "1.047411444", 
"1.048390581", 
"1.057811121", "1.060218978", "1.065395654", "1.06921167", 
"1.071509648", 
"1.073730469", "1.076014602", "1.077266637", "1.079983072", 
"1.083003953", 
"1.086196504", "1.086445657", "1.0867266", "1.0905", "1.092152628", 
"1.094730942", "1.095692666", "1.1074142", "1.109534807", 
"1.111154446", 
"1.111188325", "1.113985094", "1.114045618", "1.128810226", 
"1.129375525", 
"1.132705479", "1.154833837", "1.155201819", "1.158940397", 
"1.161348047", 
"1.162953533", "1.175788329", "1.178036097", "1.179280397", 
"1.18116463", 
"1.198506534", "1.203134068", "1.207592892", "1.208610568", 
"1.212525667", 
"1.212841855", "1.214403157", "1.216756112", "1.228462377", 
"1.23305986", 
"1.241758242", "1.258212878", "1.265571914", "1.265707797", 
"1.272666444", 
"1.279325988", "1.289559543", "1.291191103", "1.296541003", 
"1.305111821", 
"1.315201411", "1.342263532", "1.344827586", "1.347944377", 
"1.352831595", 
"1.377717391", "1.37771934", "1.385440181", "1.403358682", 
"1.411889597", 
"1.412269549", "1.412544902", "1.433843384", "1.444088526", 
"1.473706353", 
"1.50172117", "1.508521601", "1.53030303", "1.532658694", 
"1.537642783", 
"1.54340949", "1.558746736", "1.595342983", "1.596774194", 
"1.596969697", 
"1.630653266", "1.702558635", "1.70468948", "1.718568102", 
"1.740819711", 
"1.760157274", "1.775510204", "1.804859813", "1.814081408", 
"1.816513761", 
"1.849050827", "1.870188679", "1.880195599", "1.887061404", 
"1.91858679", 
"1.929152149", "1.944140197", "1.946996466", "1.986547085", 
"2.007683864", 
"2.070983811", "2.099778271", "2.156359393", "2.159613059", 
"2.163963964",      "2.25951087", "2.261603376", "2.329896907", 
"2.402555911", "2.414500684", 
"2.444075305", "2.450268817", "2.484520124", "2.51119403", 
"2.515064562", 
"2.526086957", "2.554", "2.609715243", "2.61965812", "2.643854749", 
"2.704166667", "2.883275261", "3.013186813", "3.02739726", 
"3.206896552", 
"3.320930233", "3.411627907", "3.688931298", "3.709677419", 
"3.748267898", 
"3.878865979", "3.936440678", "3.994230769", "33.15909091", 
"4.095854922", 
"4.29330254", "4.390957447", "4.514634146", "4.6367713", 
"4.847665848", 
"5.284023669", "5.387755102", "6.171339564", "6.183908046", 
"6.36121673", 
"6.847826087", "7.003496503", "7.193220339", "8.160550459", 
"8.751879699"
), class = "factor"), MnFe = c(0.012176723, 0.010329834, 
0.009460859, 
0.004488071, 0.0033725, 0.003435313), MnIncCoh = c(169.4430276, 
331.1977339, 490.5686845, 279.5752228, 272.3091921, 286.0408118
), CuRb = c(0.392971246, 1.484304933, 0.735426009, 0.491651206, 
1.142857143, 0.4345898)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for exactly.  But to get started, the plot definition should look like: `ggplot(wapITRAX, aes(x = BrTi, y = Depth))`.  See if this works for your first plot.  To plot the others, you will need to reshape your data, in which case, please edit the question and paste in the output of `dput(wapITRAX)`.

Comment: Hi Dave2e, I have added an image of the type of graph I am trying to achieve to the main text. Thanks, your first tip worked and so now I can plot one element at a time. Unfortunately, my dput output is so large it exceeds the limit allowed. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your posted data.  This should approximate the desired design.

First step, Transform the data from a wide format to a long format using the `pivot_longer` function from tidyr.

Then plot the data using "depth" as the independent variable and the parameters' values as the dependent variables.
Then use `facet_wrap()` to separate the plots.  `coord_flip()` will make the independent variable (Depth) appear on the y-axis.

```
#fixed 1 column of data.
originaldata$ZrRb <- as.numeric(as.character(originaldata$ZrRb))
library(tidyr)
#Make wide
wapITRAX<-pivot_longer(originaldata, -1, names_to="parameter", values_to = "value")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(wapITRAX, aes(x = Depth , y = value))+
   labs(x = "Depth (cm)")+
   geom_line() +
   theme_classic() +
   coord_flip() +
   scale_x_reverse() +
   facet_wrap(vars(parameter), nrow=1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just tried that this morning and it works perfectly!